# Displaying read more link with the_content

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the "read more" link at the bottom of my blog excerpt with the option set to content in the theme. I can't figure out what code to put where. I don't know how to apply the codex recommendation

```
<?php 
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            if ( $blog_content == 'Content' ) { 
            the_content( '', FALSE, '' );
     }  
           else if ( $blog_content == 'Excerpt' && $excerpt != '' ){
            the_excerpt('',FALSE,'');
 } ?>
```

Thanks for any feedback in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using get_the_excerpt that tag must be used within the loop.
So on page.php or single.php would be an example.